# How to pass WordPress page styling (css) along with page contents via JSON and REST API

Tags: json, wordpress, elementor, wordpress-rest-api

I am learning the technique of passing JSON of a WordPress page built with Elementor Pro, to a mobile app-building framework such as node.js via WordPress REST API.

I am able to view the JSON of the page using the url format, e.g. if the website is site.com -
site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/page-id

My query -

The rendered HTML of the page inside JSON contains a number of Elementor classes / IDs (e.g.  etc) and other classes / ID used by the theme / plugins. How to pass the entire styling (css) for the entire page through the JSON? so that the recipient mobile app building framework can fetch all the page styling along with page content and reconstruct the entire page along with the styling, as output?

I tried viewing the JSON of the page using the url format, e.g. if the website is site.com -
site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/page-id

I was expecing that the entire styling for the entire WordPress page rendered as HTML would be present inline in the JSON.